# Apportioning data in Excel such that it matches the summary data

Tags: excel-formula

I want to apportion across rows(product groups) and columns(stores) in such a way that row total as well as column total matches

e.g.
I have store total as follows
[image: store wise total]

and product group wise total as follows
[image: product group wise total]

and store productgroup wise data as given below
[image: store product group wise grid]

I want to apportion in such a way that my store wise numbers match (in link1)and productgroup wise numbers also match(in link2)

Comment: What format is you data in now and what have you tried?

Comment: The data is in excel format and I have apportioned it store MIx wise, so it matches store numbers but then product group numbers don’t match. If I apportion using product groip mix then store numbers don’t match.

Comment: In the third picture that you posted there are some inconsistencies. For example, in group G you have 1 sale but it is not apportioned to any group.

Comment: The figures are in crore so may be not visible due to decimals

Comment: Is the third picture the original data source?

Comment: Yes  it is original data

Comment: Did you try `=sumif(B1:F1,"Store Number", B2:B22)` for the store number and a similar formula for the product group?